# Creating ghost trail effects

Tags: graphics, animation, visualization

Does anyone know how to create a ghost trail effect? For a simple example look at this screenshot:

[image: Ghosting Effect]

You can find the actual animation [here](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/ghost/GhostingEffect.html). What I would ultimately like to see it happen is to make the object move based on whatever equations you specify it. For instance, to make it move around a circle the object should have the position `(cos[t], sin[t])`. Or, lets say you have a list of specified coordinates `{(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ..., (xn,yn)}`, All I want to be able to see is the trace as an object takes in the coordinates I specify.

Here is a simple ball moving without the ghosting effect.

```
Animate[
 Graphics[
  Disk[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, .25],
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
  ImageSize -> 400, 
  Axes -> True
 ],
 {u, 0, 6}
]
```

[image]

Comment: As you asked for, I've added the gif animation code to R.M's answer - the "DisplayDuration" setting is measured in seconds, and as far as I know one  shouldn't go below `0.03` to avoid display problems in certain browsers.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is a simple approach to create a ghost trail:

```
obj[{xfunc_, yfunc_}, rad_, lag_, npts_][x_] := MapThread[
 {Opacity[#1, ColorData["SunsetColors", #1]],
  Disk[{xfunc@#2, yfunc@#2}, rad Exp[#1 - 1]]} &, 
 Through[{Rescale, Identity}[Range[x - lag, x, lag/npts]]]]

frames = Most@Table[Graphics[obj[{Sin[2 #] &, Sin[3 #] &}, 0.1, 1, 500][u], 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300,
  Background -> Black] ~Blur~ 3, {u, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];

Export["trail.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> .03]
```

[image]

Comment: Can someone upload a faster version of the gif? I forgot to set the duration and I got to run now.

Comment: I uploaded a faster gif, don't look too long or you'll get dizzy.

Comment: @Jens, Can you show us the uneducated on making gifs how to do it?

Comment: @R.M hope you don't mind I added the gif export code to your answer.

Comment: And if you do mind: stare at the animation and repeat after me: "My limbs are getting heavy, I feel sleepy, I don't mind, I don't mind anything,..."

Comment: @Jens, thanks for the export code. @R.M, I'm sorry to ask but could you just show for completeness (mainly because I can't figure it out) how to adapt the `obj` to a set of points instead of functions? For instance, say `pts = Table[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/200}];` Now we want the circle to follow those points. Thank you.

Comment: @jmlopez You could do that using `Interpolation`http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html

Comment: @Jens Thank you for putting it in! :)

Comment: @R.M I really like your [animation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zcVCp.gif)!

Comment: Nice use of a Lissajous curve! One little thing: your `obj[]` routine can be simplified a tiny bit: `obj[{xfunc_, yfunc_}, rad_, lag_, npts_][x_] := MapThread[{Opacity[#1, ColorData["SunsetColors", #1]], Disk[Through[{xfunc, yfunc}[#2]], rad Exp[#1 - 1]]} &, Through[{Rescale, Identity}[Range[x - lag, x, lag/npts]]]]`. No scoping constructs needed!

Answer (score 59):

The idea behind this solution is to construct a superposition of Gaussian surfaces whose amplitude decay in time, and use `DensityPlot` to plot the trail:

```
trail[fun_, {t_, tmin_, tmax_, dt_}, k_, lam_][xxx_, yyy_] :=
  Module[{trange, xrange, yrange, twindow, trailf, sel, decayf},
   decayf[x0_, y0_, t0_] := Exp[-k t0 - lam^2 (x0^2 + y0^2)];
   twindow = 6/k;
   trange = Range[Max[tmin, tmax - twindow], tmax, dt];
   {xrange, yrange} = Transpose[fun /. t -> # & /@ trange];
   Fold[Function[{ff, pt}, 
      Evaluate[
        ff[#1, #2, #3] + (1 - ff @@ pt) decayf[pt[[1]] - #1, 
           pt[[2]] - #2, tmax - pt[[3]]]] &], 0 &, 
     Transpose[{xrange, yrange, trange}]][xxx, yyy]
   ];
```

In `trail`, `fun` is the path of the particle, `tmin`  is the starting time, `tmax` is the current time, `dt` is the step size in time, and `{xxx, yyy}` are the coordinates at which you want to evaluate the function. The parameters `k` and `lam` determine the length and width of the trail where greater values for the parameters correspond to shorter/narrower trails.

**Example**

```
Monitor[tab = 
   Table[DensityPlot[
     Evaluate[
      trail[{Cos[t], Sin[t]} + .5 {Cos[2 t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, 0, tt, 
         Pi/40}, 2, 5][x, y]],
     {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"],
    {tt, Pi + Range[40]/40 2 Pi}], tt];

Export["~/Desktop/trail3.gif", tab]
```

[image: trail]

Comment: Pretty, as expected. :-)

Comment: Very nice indeed! +1 and if I could I would give some more.

Comment: I love the graphics, but, is it possible to show the axes also, maybe change the color scheme? I'm having trouble doing the pretty rendering with a set of fixed points using the function `Interpolation`, any ideas of how to make it faster?

Answer (score 28):

With a bit of blur, but still not the variable-width blur in the example.

```
obj[{xfunc_, yfunc_}, rad_, lag_, npts_][x_] := 
 With[{trail = 
    Range[x - lag, x, lag/npts]}, {ColorData["SunsetColors"]@#1, 
     Opacity@#1, Disk[{xfunc@#2, yfunc@#2}, rad]} & @@@ 
   Transpose[{Rescale[trail], trail}]]

frames = Most@
   Table[ImageCompose[# ~Blur~ 4, 
       MapAt[Last, Show[#, Background -> None], 1]] &@
     Graphics[obj[{Cos, Sin}, 0.05, 1, 100][u], 
      PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> False, 
      ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> True, Background -> Black], {u, 0, 
     2 Pi, .1}];

Export["trail.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> .03]
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

I saw this question rather late, and I can't quite hope to outdo the very fine answers already given, so please allow me to share my modest attempt at a three-dimensional implementation of the ghost trail:

```
trail[f_, {t_, head_, len_}, r_, opts___] := 
 Block[{gc = First[Cases[ParametricPlot3D[f, {t, head - len, head}, 
       ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#4], Glow[ColorData["SunsetColors", #4]]] &), 
       Evaluate[Apply[Sequence, FilterRules[{opts}, 
          Options[ParametricPlot3D]]]]], _GraphicsComplex, Infinity]]},
  Graphics3D[{CapForm["Round"], JoinForm["Round"], 
    MapAt[gc[[1, #]] &, First[Cases[gc[[2]], 
       Line[l_, rest___] :> Tube[l, Map[Scaled[r #] &, 
          Exp[Cases[VertexColors /. gc[[3]], Opacity[op_] :> op - 1, Infinity][[l]]]], 
         VertexColors -> (VertexColors /. gc[[3]])[[l]]], Infinity]], 
     1]}, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 25}, 
   Evaluate[Apply[Sequence, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics3D]]]], 
   Axes -> None, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False]]
```

I only wish to note three cute things about this particular implementation (that is, apart from the additional degree of freedom (via `ViewPoint`) provided by having three dimensions):

1. We can leverage the adaptive sampling capability of `ParametricPlot3D[]` so that the curve traced out by the ghost trail is sampled only where it matters. (If need be, `trail[]` can of course take the `PlotPoints` option.)
2. `Tube[]` supports a varying radius across its body. None of the two-dimensional primitives have an equivalent capability.
3. The `Opacity[]` directive in the `ColorFunction` option setting, in addition to its obvious purpose, allows the trapping of the (scaled!) parameter values used in the sampling of the curve. These values are then easily retrieved for the conversion into the list of radii needed by `Tube[]`.

As with R.M, I shall be using a Lissajous curve (the three-dimensional equivalent in this case) to demonstrate `trail[]`:

```
lissajous3D[n_, d_, a_, b_, c_][t_] := {a Sin[2 Pi n t + d], b Sin[2 Pi t], c Cos[2 Pi t]};

trailFrames = Table[Blur[trail[lissajous3D[3/4, 0, 9, 8, 4][t], {t, h, 1/5}, 1/100, 
                        ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-9, 9}, {-5, 5}}]],
                    {h, 0, 4 - 2/25, 2/25}];

Export["trail3D.gif", trailFrames, "DisplayDurations" -> .03]
```

[image: 3D ghost trail]

Comment: Other fun space curves to try include [torus knots](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes3d/solenoidtoric/solenoidtoric.shtml) and [clelies](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes3d/clelie/clelie.shtml).

Answer (score 16):

In version 9, there is a new command `ReplaceImageValue`, and that got me thinking if it could be used to superimpose images more quickly. As an application, this question seemed to be a good illustration, especially under the aspect of speed.

To demonstrate a comparatively fast ghost trail effect, I tried this, and got a fun responsive interaction:

```
DynamicModule[{step, stencil, im, q},
 Dynamic[
  With[
   {
    pos = MousePosition["Graphics"] /. None -> {200, 200}
    },
   q = q + step[pos - q];
   im = ReplaceImageValue[
     ImageMultiply[im, .9],
     stencil /. Rule[arg1_, arg2_] :> Rule[q + arg1, arg2]
     ]
   ]
  ],
 Initialization :> (
   stencil = Map[Rule[
       # - {8, 8}, 
       Blend[{Yellow, RGBColor[0.3, 0., .3]}, 
        Norm[# - {10, 9}]/10.]] &,
     Position[DiskMatrix[7], 1]
     ];
   im = Image@Array[0 &, {300, 300}];
   q = {150, 150};
   step[v_] := 4. ArcTan[Norm[v]/3] Normalize[v]
   )]
```

[image: ghost trail]

Here the mouse controls where the ghost trail is heading. It follows the mouse in real-time.

To really exploit `ReplaceImageValue` here, I defined the bright spot in `stencil` as a disk with a gradient of colors using `DiskMatrix[7]` and assigning colors based on the distance from a point near its center. I deliberately offset that point: it's the subtracted value in `Norm[# - {10, 9}]`. If you replace `{10, 9}` by `{8,8}` you'll see that the offset gives the appearance of 3D lighting from one side.

To make the actual ghost trail, I used `ImageMultiply` on the currently displayed image `im` which darkens all pixels at every frame, so that the most recently added pixels from `ReplaceImageValue` appear brighter than the older pixels.

The position at which the `stencil` containing the disk is drawn is called `q`, and it gets updated by an increment in the function `step` which is directed toward the mouse but isn't allowed to jump too far ahead so that the trail doesn't get ripped into disjoint pieces (that's limited by the `ArcTan`).