# How can I make a list animation of images that fade in and out?

Tags: dynamic, animation, image

I'm not sure how to get a "fade in" effect.

Comment: Is [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5867/125) or some variant of it relevant/useful?

Comment: @kguler Thanks. I think it's useful, but a different question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start from understanding and setting up an transition functions sequence:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[(1 + Tanh[tr (x - dt n)])/2, {n, 1, Length[imgs], 1}], {x, 0, 
  dt (Length[imgs] + 1)}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Set your images as a list:

[image]

Set 2 main parameters of your animation:

```
tr = 1;(* transition speed *)
dt = 4;(* display time *)
```

Finally use interactive interface

```
Animate[Overlay[Table[SetAlphaChannel[imgs[[n]], (1 + Tanh[tr (x - dt n)])/2], {n, 1, 
    Length[imgs], 1}]], {x, 0, dt (Length[imgs] + 1), 
  ImageSize -> Small}, AnimationRate -> 2]
```

[image]

Or make a table and export as an .GIF image

```
gift = Table[Overlay[Table[SetAlphaChannel[imgs[[n]], (1 + Tanh[tr (x - dt n)])/2], {n,
       1, Length[imgs], 1}]], {x, 0, dt (Length[imgs] + 1), 
    dt (Length[imgs] + 1)/50}];

Export["MyVacationSlideShow.gif", gift]
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use the hyperbolic tangent; any number of "sigmoidal" functions ought to do the trick...

Comment: Lovely answer Vitaliy! See my answer below...

Comment: @J.M.Absolutely, I just like Tanh ;-)

Comment: @Mike Thanks, your solution is cool too! +1

Comment: This is good, but very slow for large `Length[imgs]`.

Answer (score 4):

Vitaliy has a great answer, however I wanted to try my hand at this to get something a bit smoother in action by using Dynamics...

```
images = ImageResize[#, 500] & /@ ExampleData /@ ExampleData["TestImage"][[1 ;; 7]];
i = 1;
Dynamic[
    Which[Or @@ Thread[i == Range[Length[images]]], Pause[2]; i += .01, 
      i < Length[images] - 1, i += .01, 
      True, i = 1]; fade = Mod[i, 1];
 ImageCompose[images[[IntegerPart[i]]], {images[[IntegerPart[i] + 1]], fade}]
]
```

This works, but can someone please tell me why I can't substitute `IntegerQ[i]` for `Or @@ Thread[i == Range[Length[images]]]`?

Comment: Re your question, i has head Real, not Integer.

Comment: Yes, `Head[1 + .01]` is `Real`; try: `i == Round[i]`

Comment: Oh right, thanks!