# Realistic jet engine flame

Tags: graphics3d, engineering

I’m trying to make rocket flame and jet engine fire that is a `Graphics3D` object so that it can be used with a 3D rocket project.

There are many types of such flames, but for starters I would like the blue flame as seen here. Any ideas?

[image: thrust vector jet flame]
[image: Blue flame]

These sites don't do what I'm looking for.

Click (http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RocketFire/)
Click ([Creating ghost trail effects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/creating-ghost-trail-effects))

I want to mimic that transparent effect of seeing through the middle of the flame that is visible in the images above. So far I have not been able to get even basic translucent effects right. Nothing I tried was even remotely like the above pictures, so my code is not very useful.

Comment: Mathematica isn't really the right tool for this.  You can create the *shape* in Mathematica, but then the best way to continue would be to export it and use a raytracer to render it.

Comment: Related: [How to create blurred Graphics3D objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6242/how-to-create-blurred-graphics3d-objects) Try `Image3D`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I guess for getting a reasonable effect one can well try to make an opacity field and then pixel by pixel evaluate the integral. Raytracer is a more general tool, which is neededed for reflection/refraction problems, but here it could be treated a bit simpler.

Answer (score 18):

Probably not that useful, but it turned out looking cool.

```
temp[x_, y_, z_] := 10000 Exp[-Sqrt[4 + (z - 5)^2]/50]*40/(40 + x^2 + y^2);
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],
  Raster3D[
   Table[Append[List @@ ColorData["BlackBodySpectrum"][#], 
       Clip[(# - 6000) (10000 - #)^2/2.5*^10]] &@
     temp[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5, 1/2}, {y, -5, 5, 1/2}, {z, 0, 30, 1/2}]]
  }, Axes -> True, Background -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great! Only now I'll be involuntarily hearing [The Prodigy](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=1QhdVISrM4KQPYeWgfAK&url=http://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dwmin5WkOuPw&ved=0CB8QyCkwAA&usg=AFQjCNF3kkc7KfLqdUB1hSIfe4xnUIHTUA&sig2=QvVb8VJA31mwbni3CqXujw)  in my head for the rest of the evening.

Comment: Nice, but need a heat control slider :)  `Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {Opacity[op],
   Raster3D[Table[Append[List @@ ColorData["BlackBodySpectrum"][#], Clip[(# - 6000) (10000 - #)^2/2.5*^10]] &@temp[x, y, z],
     {x, -5, 5, 1/2}, {y, -5, 5, 1/2}, {z, 0, 30, 1/2}]]
   },Axes -> True, Background -> Black],
 {{op, .5, "How hot?"}, 0, 1, .1},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 Initialization :>
  (temp[x_, y_, z_] := 10000 Exp[-Sqrt[4 + (z - 5)^2]/50]*40/(40 + x^2 + y^2)
   )]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K4LSn.png)

Comment: @Michael E2 Very cool!!

Comment: love the graphics ! +1